# Cut through, pull up epoxy mix floor

Tags: flooring, epoxy

Advice on tearing out epoxy/stone mixed flooring

Hello, my wife and I bought a home a number of years ago.  The upstairs bathroom floor has tile over one of those epoxy mixed with small pebbles in a bucket and poured on what I am guessing is plywood.

The previous owner mentioned it and said it didn't turn out well, they had tiled over it leaving a step up of about an inch, maybe slightly more.

I want to tear it all out and lay down new tile.  I'm not worried about popping up the existing tile as it's partially lose in spots.

But how can I get under this epoxy mix?  I'm thinking some type of blade on a circular saw?  The floor area is about 9x7.

Would a diamond grinding wheel blade work? Or some other thought

*Edit.
I'm not terribly worried if I have to replace plywood.  I'm more concerned about the tile on the wall and getting it free from it. I'm not certain but it looks like the walls were done first and then the floor poured/put down.  There are not any baseboards currently, that's always an option for me if needed in the end.

Comment: Diamond probably the best.  If done decently the epoxy will be bonded to the plywood, so new plywood will be needed after.  I would cut in sections small enough to carry(plywood plus epoxy plus stone).

Comment: I have only seen that type of floor removed from a cement slab.  The crew used a torch to heat it to the consistency of taffey and scraped it up.  That won't work in your bathroom. Since it is on plywood, I'm inclined to believe the plywood and all need to be removed.

Comment: Yeah the plywood is toast here, so forget any dreams of peeling up the epoxy without trashing that. I suppose you could *try* a steam wand or similar non-flame source of heat.

Comment: Dry ice (careful of the ventilation so as not to asphyxiate yourself or others) and a hammer would be the other approach - make it brittle with cold and shatter it.

Comment: The problem will be prising up the ply from the (presumably) joists underneath. If you’re lucky, it’ll just have been pinned down. But more likely screwed. Prying up and then sawing through the screw shaft should work but you’ll have to reveal enough using crip659’s method to get flexibility to lever up and access for a saw or possibly metal multi tool blade.

Comment: +1 to @crip659 but be careful to set your cutter to a depth that won't ruin anything below the plywood.

Comment: Well the tile runs under the vanity and the vanity is liquid nailed to shims which are liquid nailed to the wall.  I could probably pry it off, but I'm not prepared to buy a vanity if it goes sideways